# Momentum loss due to friction in a system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, friction, dissipation

Consider two physically isolated objects. Object $A$ approaches $B$ with some initial velocity $v$ and slides over $B$ and due to friction both objects become relatively hot (compared to their initial temperature). This heat is then lost to the colder environment.

Can such a system of these two objects lose significant amount of momentum and energy in this way? Say 1% of their combined initial momentum?

Comment: If they have friction between each other, they are not individually isolated. If they are allowed to have a heat sink into the surrounding environment, they are not isolated from that environment. Your logic has a built-in contradiction in itself.

Answer (score 0):

*From the law of conservation of momentum*, the momentum of an isolated system is a constant. A system is considered isolated if there is no net *external* force acting on the system. Then the vector sum of the momenta $mv$ of all the objects of a system cannot be changed by interactions *within* the system.

Consider your objects A and B as being two blocks of equal mass which together constitute a system (See the figures below). Let B be initially at rest on a frictionless surface. Block A has an initial horizontal velocity of $V_i$ with respect to block B just prior to contacting and sliding upon block B where there is kinetic friction between them. Block B does friction work on block A bringing it to rest on block B. Block A exerts an equal an opposite force on block B (Newton's 3rd law) causing it to accelerate forward (as it is the net external force on B).

The final condition (FIG 2) has both blocks moving together with a final velocity $V_f$. The situation is analogous to a completely inelastic collision between two objects, except that friction for the inelastic collision is internal friction instead of surface friction.

Ignoring air resistance, the only *external* forces acting on the two block system are the downward force of gravity and the equal and opposite normal force acting upward on block B, for a net vertical force of zero. Given that the friction force between the blocks is an interaction *within* the system, the two block system is an isolated system and therefore momentum of the two block system must be conserved.

The initial momentum of the system is that of block A, which is $mV_i$. The final momentum of the system is that of the two blocks moving together of $mV_{f}+mV_{f}=2mV_f$. For conservation of momentum,

$$mV_{i}=2mV_f$$ thus
$$V_{f}=\frac{1}{2}V_i$$

The initial kinetic energy of the system is

$$KE_{i}=\frac{1}{2}mV_{i}^2$$

The final kinetic energy of the system is

$$KE_{f}=\frac{1}{2}(2m)V_{f}^{2}=mV_{f}^{2}=m\biggl (\frac{V_{i}}{2}\biggr)^2=\frac{1}{4}mV_{i}^2$$

For a loss of kinetic energy of $\frac{1}{4}mV_{i}^2$ which is eventually dissipated as heat.

As a final point, if A alone is considered to be the system then the friction force exerted on it by B would be an external force on the system, and the momentum of A alone will not be conserved (it decreases). The same would apply to B if B alone is the system as its momentum will increase.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't make sense. this means heat transfer to the environment doesn't change the momentum of the system (system is both $A$ and $B$ combined). That can't be correct?

Comment: It is correct. The same applies to an inelastic collision except that the friction is internal to the objects instead of surface friction. Momentum is conserved but macroscopic KE is not. Check this out: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/inecol.html#c3

Comment: I understand that. but what about the momentum loss to environment? i understand the formula but that is a problem in which environment is not taken into account.

Comment: There is no momentum lost to the environment if the system is isolated. There is only energy lost to the environment. I will attempt to include an example in my answer.

Comment: Tell me why you think momentum is lost to the environment. What is your definition of the system and what is your definition of the environment? For example, I am visualizing object B being say a block initially at rest on a frictionless surface when object A with some initial velocity contacts and slides to a stop on B with friction, following which both A and B move together at some final velocity.  A and B are thus an isolated system with the friction force internal to the system and the environment consisting of the frictionless surface under B and the air surrounding A and B.

Comment: I would add that, in my example, I am assuming  any air resistance force to be negligible.

Comment: @xyz See update to my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @xyz momentum is not conserved for system A, momentum is not conserved for system B, however, momentum *is* conserved for system AB, because there are no net external forces. Since internal forces in system AB are doing work, then energy is not conserved for the system.